# Change iframe src using input type text

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to make dynamic src chnge with url from input.
This is my code:

```
    ﻿<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Web</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="id">
    <input type="button" value="Change site" onClick="newSite()">
</form>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="www.google.com"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function newSite() {
            var site = $('#id').val();
            document.getElementById('iframe').src = "http://" + site;
        }    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So my questions are:
How to send form with by pressing enter? And, why it doesn't work?

Thanks for Your answers.

Comment: Does it work if you press the button? Try closing your inputs with a slah at the end like `<input type="text" />

Answer (score 0):

Do provide full url in text box.

```js
function newSite() {
  var site = $('#id').val();
  var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
  iframe.src = site;
  iframe.src = iframe.src;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Web</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
     <input type="text" id="id" />
     <input type="button" value="Change site" onClick="newSite()" />
 </form>
  <iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.lipsum.com/" width="900" height='500'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```